# google charts: timeline: dynamic height with scalebar position

Tags: charts, google-visualization, visualization, data-visualization

Thanks for viewing and answering.
I am using Google Charts (TimeLine) to display information from database.
But the Google Chart reference only provide setting fix height for the chart. 
Whereas I would like to change chart height based on the number of rows I get from data.
So I made the code:

```
    var graph = $('#chart_timeLine').children()[0].children[0].children[1];
    $(graph).css('height',graph.scrollHeight);
    $(graph).css('overflow-y','auto');
```

Now the chart don't have a vertical scrollbar and I am satisfied.
But I found that the scalebar, which shows the the scale of timeline chart is missing.(It is actually hiding under the chart, instead of showing up at the bottom of the chart).

So then I changed scalebar's position to absolute and set it to the bottom of my chart.
Then it is ugly because it has a height of 200px, while the scale is at the bottom of that 200px, leaving a huge blank between my chart and the scale.

Is there a fix for that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of messing with the internal workings of the chart, set the height based on the number of rows of data in the DataTable:

```
// set a padding value to cover the height of title and axis values
var paddingHeight = 40;
// set the height to be covered by the rows
var rowHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 15;
// set the total chart height
var chartHeight = rowHeight + paddingHeight;
```

and then in the Timeline's options, set the height:

```
height: chartHeight
```

Comment: I see, thank you. The idea works every well, even though I tried this implementation but it doesn't work perfectly. I jumped back to fix height cause using dynamic height would eventually achieve the same effect as fix height.(Scrolling is inevitable, and in my case it doesn't matter if it is the whole page or the chart itself anymore). Appreciate your effort.

Comment: @asgallant I would hug you right now if I could.  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work so well for concurrent events, as the number of rows in the table are the same, but the events are displayed stacked.

Comment: @RobertSirre did you manage to fix for stacked rows and dynamic height?

Comment: @bo-oz unfortunately, no. I think it would require interfering too much with the inner workings of the chart itself, which might break on the next release by Google.
Having said that, I haven't tried this yet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29821132/201019
Ah I guess you have already found it :)

Answer (score 5):

I tried the answer, but it did not work for me.  The way I got it to work for me was this:

```
    // Calculate height
    var rowHeight = 41;
    var chartHeight = dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * rowHeight + 50;

    var options = {
        height: chartHeight
    }
```

The + 1 to the getNumberOfRows() is for the X-axis text.

Comment: This still do not find the exactly height.

Comment: @Khrys that's because `dataTable.getNumberOfRows()` returns number of data items, not the number of rows in a chart. Number of rows in a chart should be calculated manually.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(jsonData){
    ...
    var options = {
      height: (jsonData.length * 40) + 80,
      timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell its:

- 30px height for each bar
- 10px padding for each group.
- 60px for the Series.

So for a 9 bar Group = (30 * 9) + 10 = 280px
Chart Height = 280px + 60px

If you are Grouping Rows you will need to determine if your date ranges overlap with any others in that group.

Google does this by:

```
Getting the Group items IN START DATE ORDER
Creating an empty array of Group Display Rows

For each Group Item:
   For each Display Row
      If Item fits in Row...
         Add it to existing Display Row
   Next

   If No existing Display row found
      Add New Display Row
Next
```

Comment: This also depends on the display resolution, it could be that two event do not actually overlap, but due to rounding they could occupy the same pixel.
It think that any attempt at reproducing this behaviour is bound to give you issues, it would be best if this would be somehow supported by the API itself.