# Prevent Google Timeline Chart from having a height of 200px if no height is specified

Tags: google-visualization

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {
            packages: ["timeline"]
        });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
            var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            dataTable.addColumn({
                type: 'string',
                id: 'JobType'
            });
            dataTable.addColumn({
                type: 'string',
                id: 'WorkType'
            });
            dataTable.addColumn({
                type: 'date',
                id: 'Start'
            });
            dataTable.addColumn({
                type: 'date',
                id: 'End'
            });
            dataTable.addRows([
                ['Excavation', 'Compaction', new Date(2015, 1, 1), new Date(2015, 1, 4)],
                ['Excavation', 'Step Push', new Date(2015, 1, 1), new Date(2015, 1, 2)],
                ['Excavation', 'Clean Road', new Date(2015, 1, 4), new Date(2015, 1, 5)],
                ['Back Fill', 'Load Fill', new Date(2015, 1, 16), new Date(2015, 1, 16)],
                ['Back Fill', 'Bob Cat', new Date(2015, 1, 16), new Date(2015, 1, 16)],
                ['Back Fill', 'Backfill', new Date(2015, 1, 17), new Date(2015, 1, 20)],
                ['Back Fill', 'Clean Road', new Date(2015, 1, 20), new Date(2015, 1, 20)],
                ['Pre Grade', 'Level Dump', new Date(2015, 2, 23), new Date(2015, 2, 23)],
                ['Pre Grade', 'Compaction', new Date(2015, 2, 23), new Date(2015, 2, 23)],
                ['Pre Grade', 'Labourer Work', new Date(2015, 2, 23), new Date(2015, 2, 26)],
                ['Pre Grade', 'Labourer Work', new Date(2015, 2, 28), new Date(2015, 2, 28)],
                ['Loaming', 'Load Loam', new Date(2015, 3, 15), new Date(2015, 3, 15)],
                ['Loaming', 'Level Dump', new Date(2015, 3, 15), new Date(2015, 3, 15)],
                ['Loaming', 'Compaction', new Date(2015, 3, 15), new Date(2015, 3, 15)],
                ['Loaming', 'Loam', new Date(2015, 3, 16), new Date(2015, 3, 18)]
            ]);
            
            var options = {
                timeline: {
                    groupByRowLabel: true
                }
            };

            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
        }
```

```html
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

I have this sample chart here: http://jsfiddle.net/ywsgmagc/
(Please just go to the actualy jsfiddle.net site, as this widget in stackoverflow doesn't allow external js files to be loaded without an extension)

As you can see, no height is specified.  According to the Google Charts documentation, the default height should be "height of the containing element".  This is not the case.

If you look at the html generated, it ads a container around the chart and sets the height to 200px.

All the SVG elements within the container have the height already specified.  How is it possible to just have it take up as much height as it needs without adding a scroll bar?

Calculating the height with an estimated row height doesn't make any sense.  I can see going through the SVG elements after it is rendered in the browser and looking for all RECT elements and getting the height of each of those elements would work... but that seems like a lot of extra work.  Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a solution (not a clever solution but it works :) :

*1) Draw your timeline a first time normally :* 
 chart.draw(dataTable, options);

*2) Get the height of the timeline :* 
 var realheight=parseInt($("#**yourtimelinecontainer** div:first-child div:first-child div:first-child div svg").attr( "height"))+70;

*3) set the real height of the timeline in options :*
 options.height=realheight;

*4) redraw :*
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);

Best regards

Comment: Best option I could find, specially when you have grouped rows. Cheers!

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rendering twice, you can add the height directly in the `options`.

If you assume that a row take ~45, you can multiply by the number of lines you have.

```js
// We assume that we have data in a list
// var data = [...]

var options = {
    height: 45 * Object.keys(data).length,
    alternatingRowStyle: false
};
chart.draw(dataTable, options)
```